# Typewriter ReturnType from IActionResult

Tags: c#, typescript, asp.net-web-api, typewriter

I have started to play around with [Typewriter](https://frhagn.github.io/Typewriter/index.html) to see if it would fit my requirements for generating both Models and an API layer.

So far, it is working for generating models, and I have it generating some sort of API Layer, however I have run into a snag when using the `$ReturnType` as demonstrated in the example [Angular Web API Service](https://frhagn.github.io/Typewriter/pages/examples.html). In the example code;

```
${
    using Typewriter.Extensions.WebApi;

    string ReturnType(Method m) => m.Type.Name == "IHttpActionResult" ? "void" : m.Type.Name;
    string ServiceName(Class c) => c.Name.Replace("Controller", "Service");
}
module App { $Classes(:ApiController)[

    export class $Name {

        constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService) { 
        } $Methods[

        public $name = ($Parameters[$name: $Type][, ]) : ng.IHttpPromise<$ReturnType> => {

            return this.$http<$ReturnType>({
                url: `$Url`, 
                method: "$HttpMethod", 
                data: $RequestData
            });
        };]
    }

    angular.module("App").service("$ServiceName", ["$http", $Name]);]
}
```

It is using `$ReturnType`, however when you are calling a .net WebApi controller with the method;

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething(){
    return Ok(MyModel);
}
```

The `$ReturnType` is `IActionResult`, which is not strongly typed enough for me. I want this to be of type `MyModel`.

Is there something I can do to get the type returned within `Ok`? Can I decorate the method with a Type which Typewriter can then read and use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so I have had no answers on this question, so I will answer it with my current solution so it might help out others.

I have created a new Attribute;

```
public class ReturnTypeAttribute : Attribute
{     
    public ReturnTypeAttribute(Type t)
    {            
    }
}
```

Which I then use to decorate my Api method;

```
[ReturnType(typeof(MyModel))]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoSomething(){
    return Ok(MyModel);
}
```

Now in my TypeWriter file, I have the following code;

```
string ReturnType(Method m) {

    if (m.Type.Name == "IActionResult"){

        foreach (var a in m.Attributes){

            // Checks to see if there is an attribute to match returnType
            if (a.name == "returnType"){

                // a.Value will be in the basic format "typeof(Project.Namespace.Object)" or "typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<Project.Namespace.Object>)
                // so we need to strip out all the unwanted info to get Object type
                string type = string.Empty;

                // check to see if it is an list, so we can append "[]" later
                bool isArray = a.Value.Contains("<");
                string formattedType = a.Value.Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "").Replace("typeof(", "").Replace(")", "");
                string[] ar;

                ar = formattedType.Split('.');
                type = ar[ar.Length - 1];

                if (isArray){
                    type += "[]";
                }

                // mismatch on bool vs boolean
                if (type == "bool"){
                    type = "boolean";
                }

                return type;
            }
        }

        return "void";
    }

    return m.Type.Name;
}
```

So as you can see, I am checking for an Attribute called "returnType", then getting the value of this attribute which is a string, removing some formatting to get to the raw object name, then returning this. So far it is working well for my needs. If anyone can think of a nicer solution, then please let me know!

It is not the best solution I was hoping for as you need to make sure you have `ReturnType(typeof(Object))` if you want the correct type in the .ts file.

Comment: Can you use `public async Task<ActionResult<MyModel>> DoSomething() {}` , which is strongly-typed ? Will Typewriter work with ActionResult instead of IActionResult  ?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I get the return type from the parameter in the method:

```
// Turn IActionResult into void
string ReturnType(Method objMethod) 
{
    if(objMethod.Type.Name == "IActionResult")
    {
            if((objMethod.Parameters.Where(x => !x.Type.IsPrimitive).FirstOrDefault() != null))
            {
                return objMethod.Parameters.Where(x => !x.Type.IsPrimitive).FirstOrDefault().Name;
            }
            else
            {
                return "void";
            }
    } 
    else
    {
            return objMethod.Type.Name;
    }
}
```

See:

[Turbocharging Your Angular 4+ Development Using Typewriter](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4313/Turbocharging-Your-Angular-4-Development-Using-Typewriter.aspx)